# InternalServiceFault when trying to connect SPGo to SP Online in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to connect the SPGo plugin in Visual Studio Code to a Sharepoint Online site. There are lots of guides for this, for instance this one: https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/saying-goodbye-to-sharepoint-designer-ac939a0b79ba

**In short, I'm doing it like this:**

1. Open VS Code
2. Open a local, empty folder)
3. SPGO: Configure workspace (follow guide, ending up with spgo.json
   looking like the one I pasted)
4. SPGO: Populate local workspace (asking me for credentials and I plot
   it in O365 style (email and password).
5. Statusbar says "Populating workspace"

After about 10 seconds I get the pasted error in the output window (spgo)

**I'm using newest versions:**

- Visual Studio Code 1.37.1
- SPGo 1.4.3

I have tried various sites in my tenant and I know they are up. I am Site Collection Administrator for the sites. I know the credentials are correct, of course. the remoteFolders and publishingScope doesn't affect anything, when changed. I assume authenticationType should be "Digest".

SPGo.json:

```
{
    "sourceDirectory": "src",
    "sharePointSiteUrl": "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName",
    "publishingScope": "Major",
    "authenticationType": "Digest",
    "remoteFolders": [
        "/SitePages/"
    ]
}
```

I don't get any files in the local folder, instead I get an error in the output:

```
================================     ERROR     ================================

<s:Fault>
  <s:Code>
    <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
    <s:Subcode>
      <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</s:Value>
    </s:Subcode>
  </s:Code>
  <s:Reason>
    <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug&gt; configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</s:Text>
  </s:Reason>
</s:Fault>
Error Detail:
----------------------
{}
===============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed this post for so long. First- thanks for the detailed write-up. This is the first time I've seen this specific issue with SPGo, so I do not know for sure what is the root cause.

Couple questions:

1. Are you using ADFS Authentication with your Office 365/SharePoint Online instance?
2. Are you able to use Addin-Only Authentication on this SP Site?

SPGo should be able to automatically work with ADFS in SharePoint Online but, as a fall-back, you could use Addin-Only Authentication. In this scenario you would create a ClientId and ClientSecret pair for the SharePoint Site Collection you are accessing and authenticate using those credentials. The ClientId would act as your UserName, and the ClientSecret would be your password.

Under the covers, I am using the node-sp-auth package for user authentication. Sergei ([s-KaiNet on Github](https://github.com/s-KaiNet)) has a great write-up on how to enable Addin-Only Authentication in SharePoint Online on his site, which you can find [here](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/node-sp-auth/wiki/SharePoint-Online-addin-only-authentication).

Thanks for using SPGo!